# Unable to find property descriptor useOriginalBody on class org.apache.camel.builder.DeadLetterChannelBuilder

Tags: java, apache-camel, dead-letter, spring-camel

I'm trying to use the deadLetterChannelBuilder but can't find the correct properties for it. does anyone know what they are or where to find them?  the one's in the doc don't seem to work. ?

Unable to find property descriptor useOriginalBody on class org.apache.camel.builder.DeadLetterChannelBuilder

```
<bean id="deadLetterErrorHandler" class="org.apache.camel.builder.DeadLetterChannelBuilder">
    <property name="deadLetterUri" value="${deadLetterQueue}"/>
    <property name="redeliveryPolicy" ref="redeliveryPolicyConfig"/>
    <property name="useOriginalBody" value="true" />
</bean>

<bean id="redeliveryPolicyConfig" class="org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryPolicy">
    <property name="maximumRedeliveries" value="3"/>
    <property name="redeliveryDelay" value="5000" />
</bean>

<camelContext
  id="com.ge.ip.mro.coreCamelContext"
  trace="true"
  xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint"
  allowUseOriginalMessage="false"
  streamCache="true"
  errorHandlerRef="deadLetterErrorHandler" >
```

I've also tried allowUseOriginalMessage  but as expected, it is not a deadLetterChannelBuilder property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct property is called `useOriginalMessage`.

`<property name="useOriginalMessage" value="true" />`